# enable only touches in html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, addeventlistener

I use JavaScript and am making a HTML5 game.

I am using buttons to buy things. Sadly I cannot use `ontouchstart='function()'` for my buttons, so I'm using the touchstart event listener, and waiting for the user to tap on a button (specifying with the button's ID).

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
  if (event.target.id === "button") {
        clicks++;
    }
}
```

What I have noticed, that because apple (i am testing on an iphone 6s with phonegap) has the 300ms delay, if the user taps the button slowly, it will do the initial tap function (adding 1 to the total amount of clicks), and then it does the function again (as if the button was clicked twice). I can expect this because I have another event listener, only for "clicks" incase the user has a computer instead of a smartphone.

Cutting to the chase, what I need is a way to disable the 2nd click.

Essentially, the number of clicks goes up by one (from 0 to 1), then you see a click animation on the button, and the total number of clicks goes up by 1 again (from 1 to 2). The touchstart event listener is causing the initial addition (what I want). Then the side effect of tapping on the button, is the button being clicked a second time without further user input.

I'd like to find a way to disable the second click part, but keep the tap.

so maybe somthing like:

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
  // disable 2nd click or clicking all together, only allowing touch events
        clicks++;
    }
}
```

I hope I explained it well, feel free to ask more questions if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, look @ https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away - in case you haven't already - to circumvent this 300ms issue.

If this isn't the case, and you want to do something hackish, maybe try

```
let lastclick = + new Date()
let clicks = 0

document.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {
  if (+ new Date() - 100 > lastclick) {
    clicks++
    lastclick = + new Date()
    console.log(clicks)
  }
})
```

to prevent clicks from happening at the same time (needs at least 100ms seperation before the second click is accepted)

Comment: Thanks for both answers!